# Find a subset of a collection of vectors that sums to $0$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Consider following practice problem on a handout from a previous year's Putnam seminar at MIT (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-a34-mathematical-problem-solving-putnam-seminar-fall-2018/).

(Problem 100). Let $M_0$ be the $2^n \times n$ matrix whose rows consist of all $2^n$ distinct vectors of $\pm 1$’s (in some order) of length $n$. Suppose that an arbitrary subset of the entries is changed to $0$’s. Show that some nonempty subset of the rows of the resulting matrix $M$ sums to the vector $[0, 0, . . . , 0]$.

Here are some observations I have made so far.

*Bounding the number of zeros*. Suppose for a contradiction that there is some resulting matrix $M$ that has no nonempty subset of rows that sums to the zero vector. In the original matrix $M_0$, pair each row with its negation, yielding $2^{n-1}$ pairs. For each associated pair of the matrix $M$, there exists some column $j$ such that exactly one vector in the pair has $j$-th entry equal to $0$; otherwise that pair would sum to zero. It follows that at least $2^{n-1}$ of the entries of $M$ are zero, and at least $2^{n-1}$ of the entries of $M$ are nonzero.

*Linear algebra*. In vector notation, we want to show that there exists a vector $x \in \{0,1\}^{2^n}$ such that $x^T M = 0$. The matrix $M$ has rank at most $n$, so the set of all *real* $2^n$-vectors $x$ satisfying this equation is a linear subspace with dimension at least $2^n - n$. Perhaps we could control the coefficients of $x$ by considering an augmented equation $x^T [ M ~M'] = 0$ for some $2^n \times p$ matrix $M'$ that enforces relationships among the coefficients of $x$. Alternatively, if we reduce everything modulo 2, then the set of vectors $x \in \mathbb{Z}_2$ satisfying $x^T M  = 0 \operatorname{mod} 2$ is also a linear subspace of dimension at least $2^n - n$. In particular, it follows that there exists a nonempty subset of the rows of $M$ that sums to a vector in $(2 \mathbb{Z})^n$.

*Parity*. Calculations for small examples suggest that there is an odd number of zero-sum row subsets. This is clearly true in the extreme cases of $M = M_0$ and $M = 0$. It would be sufficient to show that each time an entry is changed to $0$, the parity of the number of nonempty zero-sum subsets is unchanged. In order to count these zero-sum subsets, it is natural to consider the (formal) function
$$
f(z_1, \ldots, z_n) = \prod_{i =1}^{2^n} \bigl( 1 + z_1^{m_{i1}} \cdots z_n^{m_{in}} \bigr) = 1 + \sum_{A} \prod_{j=1}^{n} z_j^{ \sum_{i \in A} m_{ij} },
$$
where the sum is taken over all nonempty subsets $A$ of $\{1,\ldots, 2^n\}$.

*Induction.* Write each row $i$ of $M$ as $r_i = (r_i^1, r_i^{-1})$ where $r_i^{-1}$ is an $(n-1)$-vector. The result follows by induction if we can find disjoint nonempty subsets $I_1, \ldots, I_{2^{n-1}}$ of the rows of the matrix (many of which may be singletons) such that (a) $\sum_{i \in I_k} r_i^1 = 0$ for each $k$; and (b) the $2^{n-1} \times (n-1)$ matrix with rows  $R_k = \sum_{i \in I_k} r_i^{-1}$ for $k = 1, \ldots, 2^{n-1}$ takes the right form to apply the inductive hypothesis.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: My thought is to pair the rows as $x, -x$.  There has to be at least one zero in each such pair.  Perhaps that helps the induction.

Comment: I am missing something. What do you mean by an entry? If all $2^n$ possibilities exist, can we change all of the rows to zeroes except two rows that are the negative of each other? That seems too easy so what exactly does it mean to change any subset of the entries to zero?

Comment: @JohnDouma I believe it means any subset of the matrix entries, in the sense that you could change the second entry of the first row to zero, then the fifth and ninth entries of the seventh row to zero, etc. etc. In particular in your case, if we do change an entire row to zero, then we can just pick our subset to consist only of that zero row. The point is that the question is asking you to show that you can pick such a subset of rows, no matter what entries someone sets to zero.

Comment: @hoboonsuan Thank you. That makes sense. We don't get to pick the rows to make the theorem true. Given any set of entries that someone sets to zero, we can still find a subset of rows that sum to zero.

Comment: Unfortunately the parity argument will not work. Starting from the $n=3$ case with rows arranged in lexicographic order, we can obtain [[1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,-1,0], [-1,1,0], [-1,1,0], [-1,-1,1], [-1,-1,-1]]. Then there are exactly two ways to get zero: row 4 + row 5, and row 4 + row 6.

Answer (score 9):

**Solution 1.** Starting with the row $r_1$ that was originally the ones vector $(1,1,\dots,1)$, we will construct a sequence of rows whose partial sums $s_k=r_1+\dots+r_k$ are all $\{0,1\}$-vectors. If at any point $s_j=s_k$ for some $j<k$, then $r_{j+1}+\dots+r_k=\bf 0$ is our desired sum. Otherwise, the $2^n$ partial sums $s_j$ are all distinct $\{0,1\}$-vectors; since there are exactly $2^n$ many $\{0,1\}$-vectors, one of these partial sums must be equal to the zero vector ${\bf0}=(0,0,\dots,0)$ as needed.

Anyway, assuming the first $k-1$ rows have been chosen, with all partial sums $s_1$, …, $s_{k-1}$ distinct, we let $r_k$ be the row that was originally $-1$ in the entries where $s_{k-1}$ has $+1$, and originally $+1$ in the entries where $s_{k-1}$ has $0$. (For example, if $s_{k-1}=(0,0,1,0,1)$, we choose $r_k$ to be the row that was originally equal to $(1,1,-1,1,-1)$, so that $s_k$ is a $\{0,1\}$-vector.) Notice that $r_k$ has not been chosen before, since for different partial sums, we choose different rows. This completes the proof.

**Solution 2.** Write $a_i$ for the $i$-th row of the original $2^n\times n$ matrix, and $r_i$ for the $i$-th row of the matrix with certain entries replaced by zeroes. We define a new $2^n\times n$ matrix $C$ with rows defined by $c_i=a_i-2r_i$; that is, $c_i$ coincides with $a_i$ in those entries that were replaced by zeroes, and has opposite signs otherwise. In particular, all entries of $C$ are either $+1$ or $-1$. Thus, for any $i$, there exists $j(i)$ such that $c_i=a_{j(i)}$. Let us now consider the sequence $i_k$ defined by the recurrence $i_{k+1}=j(i_k)$ (with $i_1$ being any arbitrary index).

Since this sequence takes values in $\{1,\dots,2^n\}$, it eventually repeats, so that $i_k=i_l$ for some $k<l$, where $l$ is taken to be minimal (so that $i_1$, …, $i_{l-1}$ are all distinct). Then
\begin{align*}
r_{i_k}+r_{i_{k+1}}+\dots+r_{i_{l-1}}
&={1\over2}(a_{i_k}-c_{i_k}) + {1\over2}(a_{i_{k+1}}-c_{i_{k+1}}) + \dots + {1\over2}(a_{i_{l-1}}-c_{i_{l-1}}) \\
&= {1\over2}(a_{i_k} - a_{i_{k+1}} + a_{i_{k+1}} - a_{i_{k+2}} + \dots + a_{i_{l-1}} - a_{i_l}) \\
&= {1\over2} (a_{i_k} - a_{i_l}) \\ 
&= 0,
\end{align*}
and we are done.

**History and references.** This problem was set by Grigoriĭ Vyacheslavovich Kondakov (Григорий Вячеславович Кондаков) as Problem 6 in the Grade 11 section (!) of the 1996 Moscow Mathematical Olympiad [1, 2]. The two solutions presented above are taken from [1]. Noga Alon told Peter Winkler about this problem, who then told Richard Stanley in October 2008 [3]. Stanley then put it on the supplementary problems list for the MIT Putnam seminar. Winkler later included this puzzle in his book [4], together with the first solution presented above.

[1] Р. М. Федоров, А. Я. Канель-Белов, А. К. Ковальджи, and И. В. Ященко. *Московские Математические Олимпиады 1993–2005* г., В. М. Тихомирова, ed. (Издательство МЦНМО, 2006), 33, 188–189.

[2] Roman Fedorov, Alexei Belov, Alexander Kovaldzhi, and Ivan Yashchenko, eds., *Moscow Mathematical Olympiads, 1993–1999* (MSRI/AMS, 2011), 18, 136–137.

[3] Richard Stanley and Peter Winkler, Personal communication (8 September 2023).

[4] Peter Winkler, *Mathematical Puzzles* (A K Peters/CRC Press, 2020), 161–162, 380.